# Como verificar a quantidade de caracteres em um campo password com jquery?

Tags: jquery

Estou precisando validar o campo senha para que fique entre 6 e 12 caracteres. Para isso, estou tentando dessa forma:

```
    $('#form').on('submit', function(event){
        event.preventDefault();
        if($('#senha').val() == "" || $('#senha').val().lenght < 4 || $('#senha').val().lenght > 12){
           $("#msg-error").html('<div class="alert alert-danger" role="alert"><i class="fas fa-exclamation-triangle"></i> Sua senha deve ter entre 6 e 12 caracteres!</div>');                      
        }else{
           .....
       }
```

O campo HTML:

```
<div class="styled-input">
    <label style="font-weight: normal" for="senha">Senha:<span style="color: red">*</span></label>
    <input type="password" name="Senha" maxlength="12" id="senha">
</div>
```

Só que não está validando. Como posso corrigir isso?

Answer (score 1):

## O problema

Repare nessa parte:

```
$('#senha').val().lenght
```

O nome certo do método é `.length`;

Agora é só reformular sua condição:

```js
$('#form').on('submit', function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();

    senha = $('#senha');
    alvo_erro = $('#msg-error');

    if (senha.val().length < 4 || senha.val().length > 12) {
        alvo_erro.html('<div class="alert alert-danger" role="alert"><i class="fas fa-exclamation-triangle"></i> Sua senha deve ter entre 6 e 12 caracteres!</div>');
    } else {
        //.....
        console.log('Passou na validação!');
        alvo_erro.empty();
    }
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title></title>

        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <meta charset="utf-8">

    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="styled-input">
            <form id="form">
                <label style="font-weight: normal" for="senha">Senha:<span style="color: red">*</span></label>
                <input type="password" name="Senha" maxlength="12" id="senha">
                <input type="submit" name="Submit!">
            </form>
        </div>
        <div id="msg-error"></div>
    </body>
</html>
```

---

**Observações:**

1. Se o campo estiver vazio, o `.length` vai retornar `0`. Óbvio!

Veja na sua condição: `... $('#senha').val() == "" || $('#senha').val().length < 4 ...`.

2. No seu código você instancia o `input` toda vez que quer buscar o valor dele: `$('#senha').val()`. É uma boa prática criar uma variável que recebe a instância (caching). Isso aumenta, relativamente, o desempenho da sua aplicação.
3. Já que a validação está sendo feita direto no cliente, o *HTML* tem, também, o atributo `minlength`.

Veja:

```
<input type="password" name="Senha" minlength="4" maxlength="12" required id="senha">
```

Lembre-se que precisa do `required` para assegurar que o `input` foi preenchido.

E o aviso fica por conta do navegador (*neste exemplo uso o Chrome*):

[image: Aviso do navegador]

Mas como nem tudo é perfeito, alguns navegadores e o Internet Explorer (ah vá) não são compatíveis. Pode conferir a [compatibilidade aqui](https://caniuse.com/#feat=input-minlength).

Answer (score 0):

Você pode fazer desta forma, o código esta comentado para melhor entendimento.

```js
//Deixei a mensagem de erro em uma função separada para que possa ser reaproveitada em outros trechos, e caso seja alterada ela será em apenas um lugar
function msgErro(mensagem){
 $("#msg-error").html('<div class="alert alert-danger" role="alert"><i class="fas fa-exclamation-triangle"></i>' + mensagem + '</div>'); 
}

$('#form').on('submit', function(event){
 event.preventDefault();
 
 // Verifica se a senha foi digitada
 if($('#senha').val().length == 0){
  msgErro('Favor preencher o campo senha');
  return false;
 }
  
 // No seu codigo você digitou lenght e o certo é length
 // Aqui verifica se o tamanho digitado esta entre 4 e 12
 if($('#senha').val().length < 4 || $('#senha').val().length > 12){
  msgErro('Sua senha deve ter entre 6 e 12 caracteres!');
  return false;
 }else{
  msgErro('');
  console.log("Tudo ok com a senha");
 }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id="form">
  <div id="msg-error"></div>
 <div class="styled-input">
  <label style="font-weight: normal" for="senha">Senha:<span style="color: red">*</span></label>
  <input type="password" name="Senha" maxlength="12" id="senha">
 </div>
  <input type="submit" value="enviar" />
</form>
```